# getting values from one table to other

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2008, join

I'm using a tables called transaction and sales where transaction contains account number, scriptname, transaction type(transactio) and Quanity; and sales table contains scriptname, account number, shares_bought and shares_sold.
If the transaction type is sell then shares_bought = Quantity else Shares_sold= Quantity. The SQL command which I have written is not working, Please tell corrections.

```
SELECT t.scriptname, s.accnum, s.shares_bought, s.shares_sold
FROM sales AS s INNER JOIN transac AS t ON s.accnum = t.accnum
SELECT CASE WHEN t.transactio = 'buy' THEN s.shares_bought=t.Quantity 
ELSE s.shares_sold=t.Quantity 
END
```

For example I have in the transaction table I have scriptname="abcd" accnum="1" transactio="buy" and Quantity="20"
In sales table I should get scriptname="abcd" accnum="1" shares_bought="20" and shares sold empty

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you correctly , you should replace the second select with and or where

```
SELECT t.scriptname, s.accnum, s.shares_bought, s.shares_sold
FROM sales s INNER JOIN transac t ON s.accnum = t.accnum
and CASE WHEN t.transactio = 'sell' THEN s.shares_sold=t.Quantity 
ELSE s.shares_sold=t.Quantity 
END
```

Comment: I am getting error near the equals of t.transactio = 'sell' which states as "Error in ON clause near '='. Unable to parse query text."

Comment: try now , you missed "n" in the word t.transaction

Comment: no bro, i deliberately made it.. it was not spelling mistake

Comment: remove the "as" before the table, i think in mysql you should remove it but not sure about it